# fetching all the data from a partially hidden list watir

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I'm trying to fetch a span of 4,600 elements

```
<span> 4,600 </span>
```

i inspected the elements and found that each element is a list class which has a child class with a title and href that i want to fetch the problem is that :

1. not all elements are visible , you would have to scroll down the api to find more elements
2. i cant seem to successfully fetch a single piece of data

`puts browser.th(:class => %w("_9irns _pg23k _jpwof _gvoze")).link.hreflang`

this is the structure of the code i'm trying to fetch

```
<ul class = 'xxx'>
<div class = 'xxa'>
<li class ='fff'>
<li class ='fff'>
<li class ='fff'>
.
.
```

the `<li class = 'fff'>` has `<a class='xxx xxx xxx xxx'>` having the data i'm trying to fetch tittle and href

to be more clear how can I iterate over all the classes of 'fff' and pick a url which is in a child class of it.

Comment: Your question is unclear, add more HTML and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use quotes inside the `%w` to find an element from a collection of classes, and try requiring `watigiri` gem and using `#text!` to obtain text of hidden elements.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. He used `%w` to convert that string into array which consists of word by word in each of its place, the easiest way he could have done is , he could have used `split`method upon the string like 'aaaa bbbb ccc.split`

Comment: %w is definitely preferred, but with quotes adds the quote itself to the array. :) Try it in irb.